# Angle between axes in a tetrahedron with equal side lengths

Tags: geometry

I am trying to determine the angle between the axes that pass through the dots in a perfect tetrahedron, where all sides are of the same length.

[image]

I'm looking for $\angle AOD$.

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: I think there is insufficient information, without knowing the distance between O and the base of the tetrahedron. Are you familiar with the method of using the dot product to find the angle between two vectors? Generally questions will be better received if you explain what you already did and where you got stuck.

Comment: All sides are same length, so AB = BC = CA = AD = BD = CD so you can take any value you want. O is the intersection point of the axies that go through A, B, C, D and land perpendicular to the plane they aim at. I got 120 degrees using my intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not 120 degrees.

You can place the vertices  in a cube,  $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of the four points are $(1,1,1);  (1,-1,-1); (-1,1,-1); (-1,-1,1)  $  while the center is at the origin $(0,0,0).$

The angle between any two of the indicated vectors is $\arccos \frac{-1}{3}$  which is about $109.5^\circ$

Comment: which is the most famous angle in organic chemistry